# TDV, YF? --- Find the letter

Tags: letter-sequence

The instructions are simple. Please find the letter that should substitute the question mark.

TDV

YF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One type of answer maybe

> B as on a standard keyboard the letters after TDV are YF*B*

Comment: Type pun! Plus one.